# 2D Array number grid with for and if

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist

I have recently started to learn java. I have a task, where I have to print a number grid with specific values in it.

Heres the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 5, 7},
                    {10, 11, 12, 14, 16},
                    {19, 20, 21, 23, 25},
                    {28, 29, 30, 32, 34},
                    {37, 38, 39, 41, 43},
                    {46, 47, 48, 50, 52}};

  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
          System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
  }


}

}
```

Now it works perfectly fine, but ideally I could only declare values of the first row and use for loop with if statement to accomplish the same thing, yet I struggle to figure out code for that.

Comment: You do not appear to have even *attempted* this modification.

Comment: My suggestion would be to just start and try something, use an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij to quickly debug big errors and then run it using the debugger in those IDEs. Spend a few hours and refine as much as you can. Then if you are still stuck, post a question with whatever code you have at that point.

Comment: You don't need an if statement; you need a way to calulcate the value to print based on the values of `i` and `j` and the first row of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two elements in a column is 9: `a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] + 9`, thus the code may be modified as:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
      int array[][] = new int[6][5];
      // initialize the first row
      array[0] = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 5, 7};  
      // print the first row
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[0]));

      for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
          // populate current row incrementing each element by 9
          for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
              array[i][j] = array[i - 1][j] + 9; 
          }
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
      }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
[10, 11, 12, 14, 16]
[19, 20, 21, 23, 25]
[28, 29, 30, 32, 34]
[37, 38, 39, 41, 43]
[46, 47, 48, 50, 52]
```

**Update**

It would be more interesting task to generate the sequence starting from 1.
Inside the row the differences between two adjacent elements change like `1, 1, 2, 2, 3`, and `3` is the difference between the last element of the previous row and the first element in the next row.

```java
int x = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
        System.out.print(x + "  ");
        x += j / 2 + j % 2;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The thing i kept doing was I initialized another int setting it as array[i][j] and adding +9 to it, but it just produced a lot of numbers.